# Question on equivalent characterization of locally constant function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A function is defined to be locally constant iff for a point there exists a neighborhood such that the function is constant on that neighborhood.

Is this equivalent to the following: Given any (convergent) sequence $x_n \to x$ then $f(x_n)$ is eventually constant?

It is clear that if $f$ is locally constant then $f(x_n)$ is eventually constant. What's not clear to me is if the other direction also holds.

Comment: The other direction holds only in certain spaces, for example first countable spaces. For the general implication, you must replace "sequence" with "net" or "filter".

Comment: @DanielFischer When you say first countable spaces do you mean the domain, the range or both?

Comment: The domain. If the domain is first countable, you can detect a non-locally-constant function (to whatever space) by a convergent sequence such that the sequence of values isn't eventually constant. If there is a point such that every sequence converging to that point must be eventually constant, but the point is not isolated, then you can't detect non-locally-constantness there by sequences.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you, I think I understand. I'll try to write an answer to my own question.

Comment: Good. If you want a concrete example, the co-countable topology on an uncountable set provides an easy one.

Comment: @DanielFischer I got stuck and I can't post my answer to my own question because I don't have enough reputation. I was trying to prove the reverse implication by showing the contrapositive but then got stuck when trying to make $x_n$ convergent. Maybe you could give me a hint on how it works, here is what I wanted to do (to be continued):

Comment: Let $f: X \to Y$ be a function between metric spaces $X$ and $Y$. $$ \\$$


We claim that $f$ is locally constant if and only if for every $x_n \to x \in X$ the sequence $f(x_n)$ is eventually constant. 
  $$ \\$$

The implication $\implies$ is obvious.

Comment: We now prove $\Longleftarrow$ by proving the contrapositive: Let there be a point $f(x) = y \in Y$ such that for every neighborhood $U$ of $y$ the map $f$ is not constant on $U$. (for convenience we should probably assume that $f(X)$ is connected and not empty) We construct a sequence $x_n$ converging to $x$ as follows: Let $x_1$ be any point with $f(x_1)$ in $B(y,1)$ not equal to $y$. Such a point exists because $f(X)$ is connected (therefore there are no isolated points).

Comment: Let $x_2$ be any point with $f(x_2)$ in $B(y, {1\over 2})\setminus \{y,f(x_1)\}$. Repeat this process for $x_n$ with $f(x_n)$ in $B(y,{1\over 2^n})$ and not equal to previously chosen points.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the reputation, you have to wait x time before you can post an answer to your own question if you have less than y rep. You don't need to assume connectedness or so. I'll post an answer, a little patience.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you, that would save me! ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, and if it's convenient restrict your answer to metric spaces. That's general enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse only holds if the domain of the map has nice properties (being first countable is sufficient, but there may be spaces where the converse holds without them being first countable).

The direction that local constantness implies eventual constantness of $f(x_n)$ for every convergent sequence $(x_n)$ is clear: Let $x = \lim x_n$. By assumption, there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ on which $f$ is constant, and by the definition of convergence, we have $x_n \in U$ for all $n \geqslant n_0$, hence $f(x_n) = f(x_m)$ for all $n,m \geqslant n_0$.

We prove that the other direction holds in first countable spaces by proving the contrapositive. So let $X$ a first countable space, and $f\colon X \to Y$ a map that is not locally constant. Then there is an $x\in X$ such that $f$ is not constant on any neighbourhood $U$ of $x$. Since $X$ is first countable, there is a countable neighbourhood basis $\{ U_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ at $x$, and we may assume $U_{n+1} \subset U_n$ for all $n$ (else consider $V_n = \bigcap\limits_{k\leqslant n} U_k$). In a metric space, we could choose e.g. open balls of shrinking radius: $U_n = B_{1/n}(x)$.

Then we construct a sequence converging to $x$ such that $f(x_n)$ is not eventually constant: For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there are points [at least one] $y \in U_n$ with $f(y) \neq f(x)$. Let $x_{2n}$ be such a point, and let $x_{2n+1} = x$. For any neighbourhood $V$ of $x$, there is an $m\in\mathbb{N}$ with $U_m \subset V$. For $k \geqslant 2m$, we have $x_k \in U_m \subset V$, so $x_k \to x$. Further, by construction we have $f(x_{2k}) \neq f(x_{2k+1})$ for all $k$, so $\bigl(f(x_k)\bigr)$ is not eventually constant.

---

If the space is not first countable, the other direction does not in general hold when considering only convergent sequences $x_n \to x$, but it would hold if one considers convergent nets or filters instead. The proof for filters is direct from the definitions, since the neighbourhood filter of $x$ is the coarsest filter converging to $x$, and the proof for nets is similar to the proof with sequences for the first countable space.